# Why, My HTML element is starting from the bottom, if i apply the display inline-block property?

Tags: html, css, styling

I want to generate the comments list like component, for that i have taken divs and applied display block and inline-block accordingly. But I don't know why my HTML element is starting from the bottom most position (If you increase and decrease you can figure it out).Pls help in this regards.

```css
.comment {
  color: red;
}

.imagePanel,
.textPanel,
.userName,
.timeStamp {
  display: inline-block;
}

.userImage {
  width: 60px;
}

.userName a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: unset;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div className='mainCommentPanel'>
  <div className='imagePanel'>
    <img className="userImage" src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_960_720.png' alt='userImage' />
  </div>
  <div className="textPanel">
    <div className="UserBox">
      <div className="userName"><a>User Name</a></div>
      <div className="timeStamp">{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
    </div>
    <div className="comment">
      <p>This page is very cool!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The element should start from the top most position in its mentioned height and width properties.

Comment: `vertical-align:top` - Hint!

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I want to know what is the reason behind it and why it is starting from bottom and Where to apply this vertical-align

Comment: Which HTML element are you talking about?

Comment: like <p>, <img/>, <a> etc.. are starting from the bottom of the assigned height and adjusting till to the top, which is completely opp to my req.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `inline-block`, by default the `vertical-align` is set to `baseline`, set it to `vertical-align: top` and you'll be good to go! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.comment {
  color: red;
}

.imagePanel,
.textPanel,
.userName,
.timeStamp {
  display: inline-block;
}

.userImage {
  width: 60px;
}

.userName a {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: unset;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.imagePanel{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class='mainCommentPanel'>
  <div class='imagePanel'>
    <img class="userImage" src='https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/04/22/35/head-659652_960_720.png' alt='userImage' />
  </div>
  <div class="textPanel">
    <div class="UserBox">
      <div class="userName"><a>User Name</a></div>
      <div class="timeStamp">{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="comment">
      <p>This page is very cool!</p>
      <p>This page is very cool!</p>
      <p>This page is very cool!</p>
      <p>This page is very cool!</p>
      <p>This page is very cool!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you have to use class attribute instead of className.

Comment: so what is your expected behavior here ?

Comment: Fine bro, as i have written this in React i used className instead of class and  i changed the attribute as you suggested also doesn't given the expected result.

Comment: The both the divs (display:inline-block) should be start from the top of the assigned width and height and its ok, even-though it doesn't fit exactly till the bottom.
But what is happening is completely opposite to this.

Comment: you can add vertical-align props to both of the divs. set it to to as .imagePanel{
  vertical-align:top;
} Default value is baseline, which fits to the bottom.

Comment: Thnx bro, i got it now.